# Как в Yii2 сделать пагинацию если запрос через findBySql?

Tags: php, yii2

Помогите пожалуйста, как мне использовать пагинацию с findBySql()???

```
$products = Products::findBySql($sql, [':id' => $id]);    
$countQuery = count($products);
        $pages = new Pagination(['totalCount' => $countQuery, 'pageSize' => 12, 'forcePageParam' => false, 'pageSizeParam' => false]);
        // var_dump($pages);die;
        $models = $products->offset($pages->offset)
            ->limit($pages->limit)
            ->all();
```

Выводит все продукты на одной странице и показывает что страниц 4, но если перейти на след страницу там пустота! СпасибО!

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте 'totalCount' => $products->count()
и укажите меньшее количество товаров на страницу если товаров меньше 12 'pageSize' => 6 например

в View вызываете widget пагинации?

В контроллере:

```
$products = Products::findBySql($sql, [':id' => $id]);    
        $pages = new Pagination(['totalCount' => $products->count(), 'pageSize' => 12, 'forcePageParam' => false, 'pageSizeParam' => false]);
        // var_dump($pages);die;
        $models = $products->offset($pages->offset)
            ->limit($pages->limit)
            ->all();
return $this->render('VIEW', compact('products', 'pages'));
```

В View:

```
<?= LinkPager::widget([
 'pagination' => $pages,
]); ?>
```